# Testing a function entirely using stubs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon, stub

I have been writing tests for the past couple of weeks now. At my place of work we are using Mocha as our test runner and Chai as an assertion library. I am also using Sinon for creating stubs and there is something that is bugging me constantly. I have written tests for a couple of functions where I stub every dependency in the function and worst I am not even considering the arguments which the function that I am testing is accepting. Let me give an example

```js
module.exports = {
  "someFunc": (arg1, arg2) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Promise.all(arg1).then(data => {
        let someArray = ourHelperLib.toArray(data);
        let someObj = ourHelperLib.toObject(arg2);
          if(someArray.length == 0){
            reject("error");
          }else{
            resolve({
              "array": someArray,
              "object": someObj
            });
          }
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
  },
}
```

1. Now when I write tests for this function, I have a case where I stub `Promise.all()` to throw error.
2. For my second test, I stub `Promise.all()` to return a false positive value and stub `ourHelperLib.toArray()` to throw error and check if the function handles it or not.
3. For my third test I stub `Promise.all()`, `ourHelperLib.toArray()` and `ourHelperLib.toObject()` to return false positives and then check the output for a resolved promise with a value that is the resultant of the operations.

From the function definition it is clear that both the arguments passed to the function are passed directly to the dependencies that I am stubbing hence I can ignore those values completely, here's what I mean

```js
const stubOurHelperLibToThrowError = argFromCaller => {
    throw new Error("This is an error");
}
```

Since I am not handling the argument passed to my stub function, I am not at all testing the function on the basis of the data that is passed into it. I am simply testing the logic structure of the function `someFunc()`.

Is this a good practice? I haven't found a lot of solid answers and since I am responsible for introducing guidelines for writing unit tests where I am working currently, this is something that I think is crucial.

Peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass promises to your function without having to stub anything for a lot of what you are describing.

---

> I have a case where I stub Promise.all() to throw error

Instead of stubbing `Promise.all`, just pass an array with a rejected `Promise` to your function:

```js
someFunc([Promise.reject(new Error('fail'))], null)
```

...which will cause the `Promise.all` to drop into the `catch` and reject with the error.

---

> I stub Promise.all() to return a false positive value and stub ourHelperLib.toArray() to throw error and check if the function handles it or not

Again, instead of stubbing `Promise.all`, just pass an array with a resolved `Promise`:

```js
someFunc([Promise.resolve('a value')], null)
```

You can either stub `ourHelperLib.toArray` to throw an error or have your `Promise` array resolve to something you know will cause `ourHelperLib.toArray` to throw.

---

> For my third test I stub Promise.all(), ourHelperLib.toArray() and ourHelperLib.toObject() to return false positives and then check the output for a resolved promise with a value that is the resultant of the operations.

Stubbing `ourHelperLib.toArray` and `ourHelperLib.toObject` is optional.  Unless they are computationally expensive (for example, if they make network calls) then it usually makes sense to call them like normal.

You can pass the data you want to give `ourHelperLib.toArray` in the array of resolved `Promise`s, and simply pass the value you want to send to `ourHelperLib.toObject` as the second argument:

```js
someFunc([
  Promise.resolve('value 1 for ourHelperLib.toArray'),
  Promise.resolve('value 2 for ourHelperLib.toArray')
], 'value for ourHelperLib.toObject')
```

...and check that the resulting `Promise` resolves to the expected value.

---

In general it is best practice to adhere to black box testing.

This function doesn't appear to have any side-effects and simply returns a `Promise` that resolves to a result based on the parameters passed.

Unless the function has computationally expensive dependencies, then whenever possible it is best to test a function like this by simply passing parameters and verifying the result.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I will surely use the approach of passing rejecting and resolving *promises* as arguments. Also thanks for confirming that there is nothing wrong with the **black-box** approach. Actually we have a lot of API handlers which have a lot of third party dependencies which do network calls and computationally expensive read write and i/o.

Comment: @VimalSheoran you're welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!